# Pattern Lock Login/Register css for resizing on iPhone 5 and 6

Tags: css

I recently purchased a registration template on Codecanyon.
http://froiden.cloudapp.net/patternlock/ .

Unfortunately, the "lock pattern" isn't responsive with iPhone 5 & 6.

How can I change the CSS to make it centered and smaller for those devices?

Thank you in advance for all help.

Comment: really weak authentication

Comment: Makz is right here. Most people are probably going to have 3 or 4 circles as their pattern. With 4, you could crack it with 10000 attempts, but with 3 it'd only take 1000. If you're using this in a production environment, be sure to limit the number of attempts people are allowed to make before their account/IP address gets locked out, otherwise you'll get people brute-forcing their way in in seconds.